# TransactionScope wrapping ORM calls, TransactionStateAborted.CreateAbortingClone exception on second call

Tags: c#, t-sql, orm, transactions

We were trying to do some integrity checks on our database state for diagnostic reasons, so we wrapped our modification ORM queries in a TransactionScope coupled with a second query that ran diagnostics - something like this:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, _maxTimeout))
{
    ORM.DeleteItem();
    ORM.CheckIntegrity();
    scope.Complete();
}
```

It's a hand-rolled ORM, and both those calls end up doing their bit in a nested transaction scope down at the bottom.  In other words, when you dig down, DeleteItem() has
using (TransactionScope newScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOptions.Required, _maxTimeout)
{...}

and CheckIntegrity() also has the same.

For the most part it's been working fine, but I've run across an odd condition. When someone puts in some bad inputs to the query, the DeleteItem() call can throw an exception.  That exception is completely caught and handled at a stack level below the wrapper.  I believe that exception is also thrown **before** it gets to nesting the TransactionScope.

But when we get down to the nested scope creation in the CheckIntegrity() call, it throws a "Transaction was aborted error" from the CreateAbortingClone constructor.  The inner exception is null.

Most every other mention of the CreateAbortingClone interaction has to do with DTC promotion (or failure thereof) and the inner exception reflects that.

I'm inferring that the abort exception on the CheckIntegrity() call is due to the fact that the DeleteItem() had thrown an exception - even though it was swallowed.

A) is that a correct inference? Is a TransactionScope sensitive to any exceptions thrown, handled or not?

B) is there any way to detect that before making the CheckIntegrity() call?  I mean other than re-doing our ORM to let the exception percolate up or adding some other global flag?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: Poking around a bit more in the debugger, I find that TransactionScope.expectedCurrent.InternalTransaction.State is TransactionStateAborted after the DeleteItem() call, shoring up my inference.  Problem is all those members are private...

Comment: Found msdn docs saying "If an exception occurs within the TransactionScope, the transaction is marked as inconsistent and is abandoned." but there's a lot left unsaid between the lines - like it doesn't appear to matter if the exception is handled a couple of call levels below the scope, and it prevents any new scopes from being nested thereafter.

Comment: Note in a bottle time - eventually I found System.Transactions.Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.Status and figured it can be used to tell if any exceptions (handled or unhandled) have spoiled your wrapping transaction.  If it's TransactionStatus.Aborted you're hosed.  It also occurred to me that you can use a wrapping transaction at an outer level to detect when any exception's been thrown.  At your far outer call, you don't _have_ to be expecting consecutive db calls into different layers.  Of course it would be better to design your code not to swallow significant events.

Answer (score 0):

I only know how this works with EF(entity framework)

```
 using (var context = new MyContext(this._connectionString))
 {

    using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {


    }
}
```

Then the Transaction is linked to the context. I am not formilar on how your code makes that connection, but may be some fancy build in stuff.

Then it is best to wrap this in a try/catch

```
try
{
   // do-stuff
   context.SaveChanges();
   //NB!!!!!!
   //----------------------
   dbContextTransaction.Commit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
    //log why it was rolled back
    Logger.Error("Error during transaction,transaction rollback", ex);
}
```

so final code would look like

```
 using (var context = new MyContext(this._connectionString))
 {

    using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
         try
         {
              // do-stuff //
              context.SaveChanges();
              ///////////////////////
              //if any exception happen, changes wont be saved unless Commit is called 
              //NB!!!!!!
              //----------------------
              dbContextTransaction.Commit();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
              dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
              //log why it was rolled back
              Logger.Error("Error during transaction,transaction rollback", ex);
         }

    }
}
```